# How to retrieve rows with same column but with different conditions in same table?

Tags: sql-server

I am having a table which will add entries for each and every updates occurred here is how my data will be

```
ID  EmpId ischange
1     100       0
2     100       1
3     101       0
4     101       0
5     101       0
```

What I need is I would like to have a query where it will return ischange value is 0 if at least 1  employee is having 1 then I don't want that record to be displayed.

I need only records with id 101

Comment: Expected result?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything? If not, lookup `EXISTS`, try something, and if it doesn't work post your attempt.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

Select the rows having the count of total rows is equal to the count of `isChange` is `0`.

**Query**

```
select [EmpId] from [tableName]
group by [EmpId]
having sum(case [ischange] when 0 then 1 else 0 end) = count([EmpId]);
```

Or, if you want the full row, then

**Query**

```
select * from [tableName] as [t1]
where not exists(
    select 1 from [tableName] as [t2]
    where [t1].[EmpId] = [t2].[EmpId]
    and [ischange] = 1
);
```

Comment: OP needs the whole row

Answer (score 2):

The easy to understand way:

```
select * from mytable
where EmpId not in (
    select EmpId from mytable
    where ischange = 1)
```

The more performant way (assuming there’s an index on `EmpId`):

```
select a.*
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.EmpId = a.EmpId
    and b.ischange = 1
where b.EmpId is null
```

Comment: You could also use a `not exists` which may perform well depending on the data

Comment: Careful with `(NOT) IN`. If any rows have the value `NULL` for `EmpID`, you'll get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @iamdave not exists requires a correlated subquery, which will never perform better. At best it will perform the same if the optimiser rewrites the query to remove it. Usually, it performs worst of all options.

Comment: @Bohemian are you sure about that? Any citation?

Comment: @larnu I am sure. You could consider me an authoritative source.

Comment: I'd rather see some research if I am honest, far too many times do people believe the words of a person without proof, and that's how rumour mills and misinformation begin. I can't simply take what you say at face value, as I can't say I've ever noticed that issue. Perhaps it depends on the expressions used within the `IN`/`EXISTS`? If so, that doesn't mean it's true all the time. Without some citation and evidence at can't simply take what you say as fact; especially if I ever were to want to inform others of the same. If I can't back up a fact, it's meaningless.

Comment: @larnu frankly, I am an expert. Any “citation” would refer to an article written by someone like me, probably less experienced than me, so me saying it’s so means it’s so. It’s not rocket science: the query inside a `not exists` must be executed for every row, so of all the ways to write the query this gives the worst performance. Such a query is called a [*correlated subquery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). The only way to avoid the performance problem is if the optimiser rewrites the query to remove the subquery, but why rely on luck?

Comment: By that definition a `IN` would perform identically then, so why say `EXISTS` would be worse when it too would be a correlated subquery? That is the essence of my quesion. An article would be great, and hence why I ask. The best way of learning is the understand, not simply be told and treat it as gospel.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't believe you, just that I'd like to actually read up first, but you don't appear to be able to offer any evidence of why `IN` is better that `EXISTS` apart from other than "trust me, I'm an expert"; one that I don't know so how can I? For example, I can off er evidence that `IN` will suffer problems with NULLs, and can thus produce unexpected results. `EXISTS` however, does not suffer that.

Comment: @larnu no. A `not in` will perform a order of magnitude better than `not exists`, because it’s essentially a rolled up join and can be easily rewritten into a join, and the subquery is not corelated - it’s run only once, not once *per row* . And btw you can’t do it with an `in`. The behavioural issue of nulls is there, but that’s got nothing to do with performance, which is what we’re discussing. Think about what the `not exists` subquery would look like - that it must be executed for every row is why it performs worst of all the options. My 2nd query is the best way to do it.

Comment: @Larnu the “evidence” is that the not exists subquery must be run every row, giving it a time complexity of O(n2). My second query, will be O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

Or even a more performant way:

```
select * from myTable t1
where not exists 
 (select * from myTable t2 
  where t1.empId=t2.empId and t2.ischange=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct [empid]
FROM [test].[dbo].[testtable1]
where [empid] not in 
(Select empid from test.dbo.testtable1 where ischange=1);
```